# installation requirements to run SSIS and DTS packages in a job

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssis, dts

my requirement is as follows. the SSIS and DTS packages are stored on the webserver (not in database) and I need to execute them on click of a button on an ASP.NET web page and be able to abort them (again by user action) if they hang for some reason. user doesn't have access to sql server management studio or enterprise manager. if I choose the third option of executing the package in a job from this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx, then what do I need to install on the WEBSERVER apart from SSIS and DTS runtime libraries for this to work? do I need to install any SQL components on the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided, under option 3 in the "Drawbacks" section:  "Agent requires installation of SQL Server engine."  Since you chose the option to run as a Sql Agent Job, the SQL Server engine is required to be installed on the webserver to use this option.